# find list of records if each records containt the value in nodejs and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

write this function for find users if contain the search value .

```
async SearchUser(type, value) {
try {
  let objr=`${type}: ${value}`;
  return await User.find({objr}).exec();
}catch(err){
console.log("SearchUser -> err", err)

  }
}
```

for example i want to search with phoneNumber , i send this request :

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/Manager/SearchUser/phoneNumber/091598
```

i want to show me list of usrs where the phone number contain `091598` .

or maybe want to search user with userName :

```
    http://localhost:3000/admin/Manager/SearchUser/userName/adm
```

i want to show me list of usrs where the userName contain `admn` .

when i run use this code it not show me any things but in data base i have records that contain this condition .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this ptoblem ????**

Answer (score 0):

the way you are creating `objr` inside `SearchUser` function is not correct.

I would suggest to change the way you're handling the search functionality on the server, As you have mentioned that way you'll have to make separate routes for same `find` functionality.

use Query based routing [(more info here)](https://coursework.vschool.io/express-params-and-query/) like below

```js
http://localhost:3000/admin/Manager/SearchUser?phoneNumber=091598
```

so on server you can access this values on `req` object like `req.query` and you'll get an object

```js
console.log(req.query);
//output
{
   "phoneNumber": "091598"
}
```

You can also pass multiple queries here like

```js
http://localhost:3000/admin/Manager/SearchUser?phoneNumber=091598&userName=adm
```

and your object will have

```js
console.log(req.query);
//output
{
   "phoneNumber": "091598"
   "userName": "adm"
}
```

Now you can pass whole `req.query` object to the `SearchUser` function and directly use it inside `User.find()`

pseudo example:

```js
router.get('/admin/Manager/SearchUser/', (req, res) => {
   const searchParams = req.query;
   console.log(searchParams); // check your params here
   
   const users = SearchUser(searchParams);
   return users;
});

const SearchUser = async(params) => {
  try {
    return await User.find(params).exec();
  }catch(err){
    console.log("SearchUser -> err", err);
  }
}
```

API URL example:
`http://localhost:3000/admin/Manager/SearchUser?phoneNumber=09159`

Comment: thanks , but my problem is this : `i want to find each user phoneNymver  Contain 0915981`

Comment: @kianoushdortaj, I have added small pseudo code example how can you achieve the same thing this way.